# Magento 1.9.0.1 Configurable product options disappear once 1 is in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have my configurable products set up and they work perfect until one is added to the cart.

As soon as one option is in the cart all of the options disappear and only the "Add to Cart" button is left... this is happening with ALL of the configurable products on my site.

So a customer can only have one of each configurable product instead of various sizes/colors of the same product. I'm hoping this is clear enough, my apologies if it is not.

My site is idahosign.com if anyone would like to take a look. You will have to log in,  I created test login for anyone who would like to view: test@test.com and password: test1234

Comment: Seems like all pages are redirect to customer/account/login/ page. Does force registration required?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, we do require registration to view. I created test login for anyone who would like to view: test@test.com and password: test1234

Comment: The problem exist. I suggest you to set default template and repeat that actions.

Comment: The error remains even with the default template. According to the error log this is the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/tonven/public_html/bestcraftvinyl.com/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 353  This is happening across multiple sites, not just this one. Another site that can be viewed for reference is bestcraftvinyl.com

Comment: Do you have modifications to the core??? As I see in your path there is error is in Configurable.php which is in /local/ folder, not in /core/...   Try to rename it and refresh all caches and check again.

Comment: I mean that Configurable.php which is in local folder is override core Configurable.php

Comment: Thank you Sharif, that fixed it! I truly appreciate the help!!

Comment: I will answer then ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have modified Configurable.php in local code pool.

Try to rename it and refresh caches and test it. If it work as expected, then the problem is in Configurable.php

This is how you know where is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that Sharif...no excuse, but kind of new to this. Thank you again for your help.